# stackexcange api get answer and comments and related qus. in single request?

Tags: stackexchange-api, stackexchange

stackexcange api get question answer and comments and related questions in single request ?

How to get Question Answers and Comments and Related questions in single query Possible ?

document : https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

I need get all in this link : https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=38692466&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true

Answer (score 0):

You can get both questions and answers with a call to [/posts](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts), and then comments for a list of question/answers from [/posts/{ids}/comments](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments-on-posts).  Related questions are from [/questions/{ids}/related](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/related-questions).

It would be too messy to stuff all that into one endpoint.

---

I'm not sure what you mean *`I need get all in this link : https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids...`*.  That doesn't include answers, comments, or related.

---

### More information:

- [Complete list of endpoints & full documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs?tab=category#docs)
- [Discussion at **stackapps.com**](https://stackapps.com/)